# How do I adjust the size of the dropdown portion of the a combobox with PyQt

Tags: combobox, pyqt

I'm creating a program where the width of column needs to be relatively narrow, but when I add a combo box I have to increase the width so that I can read the listings in the drop down. I know that in HTML the drop down adjust to the length of longest entry, in Iron Python you can adjust the drop down width manually, but I can't seem to find any reference to either of these options in PyQt.  If I'm missing it in the documentation, a friendly pointer to the right spot would be of great help.  Thanks.

Comment: Reading the title a little more closely, I take it you want to change the width of the dropdown portion of the combobox independently of the widget's width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown portion is a component that inherits `QAbstractItemView` (usually `QListView`).
It is accessible via the `view()` getter of the `QComboBox`. You can play with its sizePolicy to get what you want.

If it is not satisfying, you can even set your own `QAbstraItemView` to the `QComboBox` via `setView'.

Comment: Perfect.  I knew it was a separate component, but didn't know that I could access it through the view() getter.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt a widgets size is usually controlled by its [layout](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlayout.html). The [layout management](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/layout.html) docs should help. In particular, take a look at [QSizePolicy](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qsizepolicy.html). If you're using designer, you can set these directly as properties, otherwise you'll need to do it in code. The [basic layouts](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/layouts-basiclayouts.html) example may help as well.